How do I Exit a Process if a Child Fails?
The program I'm working with requires a secondary executable to run (for asset compression). For error handling reasons, I need the return value of the child process. According to the system man page,

If all system calls succeed, then the return value is the termination status of the child shell used to execute [the] command.  (The termination status of a shell is the termination status of the last command it executes.)

According to this, my system call's return state should be the called process's return value. But it doesn't seem to be. Instead, when the Generator returns EXIT_FAILURE, the program receives an EXIT_SUCCESS, or 0. Am I misunderstanding something?
My code is below.
// Checks to see if the generator still exists using access().
bool asset_generator_availability = CheckAssetGenerator();

if (!asset_generator_availability) LogMessage("Assets already generated.");
else
{
    LogWarning(
        "Assets still uncompressed and unformatted. Running the Generator.");

    u8 generator_state = system("./AssetGenerator && rm AssetGenerator");
    // Here is the problem line.
    if (generator_state == EXIT_FAILURE) exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
}


You stopped reading the man page too early: In the last two cases, the return value is a "wait status" that  can be examined using the macros described in waitpid(2).  (i.e.,       WIFEXITED(), WEXITSTATUS(), and so on).

@tofro Ah, okay. How would one use those functions, though?

"Exit code" confusingly refers to both the value returned from main, and the integer returned by wait which contains this value, but shifted. In this case, it refers to the latter. Use the macros from wait's docs.

@ikegami The man page for waitpid has shed very little light on what either of those functions does. Is there a secondary reference I should see?

Updated with a link which documents the macros (not functions) clearly.

This issue is occurring because when system successfully runs the called process it doesn't return the direct return value of the process run. It instead returns a "wait status" that can be examined using the macros described in waitpid(2). (i.e., WIFEXITED(), WEXITSTATUS(), and so on).
The manual pages have more detail on this matter but for your code you could use WIFEXITED and WEXITSTATUS as follows:
if (WIFEXITED(generator_state) && WEXITSTATUS(generator_state) == EXIT_FAILURE)
{
exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
}

In this code WIFEXITED checks that the child exited normally, and WEXITSTATUS checks the exit status of the child. However, system also provides other return values if the command is null, a child process can't be created or it's status can't be retrieved, a shell can't be executed in the child process. To account for these you can use a few other waitpid macros as follows:
if (generator_state == -1)
{
    exit(EXIT FAILURE);
} //exits if system fails to create the child process or retrieve it's status.
else
{
    if (WIFEXITED(generator_state))
    {
        int exit_status = WEXITSTATUS(generator_state);
        if (exit_status == EXIT_FAILURE)
        {
            exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
        } //exits on the failure in the child code. You could add other failures in the same way.
        else
        {
        //Handle successful completion of the asset generator.
        }
    }
    else if (WIFSIGNALED(generator_state))
    {
        int signum = WTERMSIG(generator_state);
        LogError("Asset Generator was terminated by signal: %d", signum);
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }// Logs if the generator is terminated by a signal, and the signal number.
    else
    {
        if (WEXITSTATUS(generator_state) == 127)
        {
            LogError("Failed to execute shell in child process.");
        } //Logs if the shell couldn't be executed in the child process.
        else
        {
            LogError("Asset Generator terminated abnormally.");
            exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
        }// Logs if the generator is terminated in some other unexpected way.
    }
}

For the sake of the example I used a 'LogError' function for separate errors since I saw you had LogWarning in your previous code, if you don't have a LogError function you could create one or use some other method to account for separate errors.
Hope this helps!
Edit: Below are the manual pages for system and wait.
https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/system.3.html
https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/waitpid.2.html

This solution seems not to have changed anything. Should I be changing the makeup of my system call as well?

Nevermind, the problem was occurring because of the u8 typecast from the system call's i32 result. It worked flawlessly. Thank you!

@Zenais system returns an int, not a u8 or a i32

@ikegami An i32 (32-bit signed integer) is what system returns, to the best of my knowledge. No?

@Zenais, No. Again, it returns an int, not an i32.

@ikegami According to https://www.gnu.org/software/gnu-c-manual/gnu-c-manual.html#Integer-Constants, "int -- The 32-bit int data type can hold integer values in the range of -2,147,483,648 to 2,147,483,647. You may also refer to this data type as signed int or signed." i32 is simply my internal type definitions for int32_t.

@Zenais, int is not guaranteed to be 32 bits. It's only guaranteed to be 16 bits. And it can be any size larger. Using int32_t is wrong. system returns an int. /// It's also a questionable practice to obfuscate the use of the standard and known int32_t.

@Anon520, Your solution is unlikely to be correct. It doesn't consider other error codes other than 1 to be errors even though it surely should. It doesn't consider the child being killed by a signal an error even though it surely should. (Yes, the OP also made those errors, but that doesn't excuse you.)

@ikegami fair point. I've updated the answer to be able to handle many of the other return values system provides, as well as any other unexpected errors.
